# Problem with reading MIFARE 13.5Mhz with MFRC522 lib

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I'm trying to read the UID of MIFARE 13.5Mhz cards with MFRC522 lib and I have defined the following function for it.

```
void getUID() {
if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
  Serial.println("Scanned PICC's UID:");
  tag = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
   {
    tag.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
    tag.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
   }
  tag.toUpperCase();
  Serial.println(tag);
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); // Stop reading
}
}
```

this function works perfectly fine in void loop() but when I call it in the following web request my esp8266 crashes.

```
controlserver.on("/searchuid", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    
    transmit = request->arg("idcode");
    if (request->hasArg("configmodule")) {
    File file = SPIFFS.open("/inputString.txt", "r");
    if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file");
    return;
    }
    getID();
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(tag);
    String content = file.readString();
    if (content.indexOf(tag) >= 0) {
    Serial.println("Found search string");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find search string");
  }    

   
    }
  });
```

and I cannot understand why, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ["Important Things To Remember"](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#important-things-to-remember) in the ESPAsyncWebServer README:

> You can not use yield or delay or any function that uses them inside
> the callbacks

Your code calls `delay()` in the callback, and calls functions that you cannot know do not call `delay()` or `yield()`.

You need to rewrite your code to follow the instructions in the web server's documentation.